# Trying to pass variables from root module to child module and getting errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, terraform-modules

I'm new to Terraform so still trying to figure out how modules work. I was working on a demo project and I successfully set up various AWS resources in the main.tf, terraform.tfvars and variables.tf (+ outputs.tf).

I'm trying now to organize the resources into modules. I set up a child module and set up its own main.tf, variables.tf and output.tf files. I referenced/declared the variables in the child main.tf to the child variables.tf file. These variables are all defined in the root terraform.tfvars file.

When I try to run "terraform init" from the root terminal, it gives this error

```
Error: Duplicate variable declaration

│

│ on variables.tf line 1:

│ 1: variable "vpc_cidr_block" {}

│

│ A variable named "vpc_cidr_block" was already declared at main.tf:7,1-26. Variable names must be

│ unique within a module.
```

And does it for basically every variable (so multiple errors at once). What am I doing wrong? I had assumed that it all automatically goes to the root terraform.tfvars file to find the value of the variable, if that's the problem. They're all named the same in the child variables.tf as they are in the root variables.tf so could that be the problem? I'm a bit lost so any help from anyone familiar with this would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: for more context, here's my syntax from the main.tf file

```
module "myapp-subnet" {
source = "./modules/subnet"
subnet_cidr_block = var.subnet_cidr_block
avail_zone = var.avail_zone
env_prefix = var.env_prefix
vpc_id = aws_vpc.myapp-vpc.id
default_route_table = aws_vpc.myapp-vpc.default_route_table_id
```

Comment: No, the problem is that you defined the same variable twice in your module.

Comment: @Marcin sorry but I'm still confused. Do you mind explaining a little more?

Comment: The error indicates that you have `variable "vpc_cidr_block"` both in main.tf and in variabiles.tf of your module.

Comment: @Marcin you were right. In a bid to copy and paste what was in my original main.tf, I forgot to delete the variables I had declared in the first few lines. Rookie error but I'm actually a rookie lol so I appreciate it a lot. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I will provide answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments. The issue was that in the module, `variable "vpc_cidr_block"` was defined twice. One definition in `main.tf` and the second one in `variables.tf`.

Comment: @codestein Did you manage to find the duplicate declaration as I explained in the answer, or still not sure why you are getting the error?